# "HP CUE-Scanning Flow Component has stopped working" trying to scan

Tags: windows-10, scanner

I am trying to scan a photo with my Ethernet-connected HP Photosmart C6280 using the latest version of HP Solution Center on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, clicking Scan Picture as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: HP Solution Center with Photosmart C6280 (Ethernet) connected]

This is something I do regularly, but now for some reason I get the following error

[image: "HP CUE-Scanning Flow Component has stopped working"]

shortly after the following:

[image: HP Solution Center with Photosmart C6280 (Ethernet) connected -- trying to start scanning]

In the Application event log, I see the following related entry:

[image: "HP CUE-Scanning Flow Component has stopped working" -- Application event log]

I have rebooted the Windows 10 PC and power cycled the printer.  Posts related to the error message that I have found online are from between 2009 and 2013: none mention or seem to have solutions that fit Windows 10.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and managed to resolve it?  Might someone simply know better than I how to approach the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: ask this the HP support. We can't fix bugs in their tools

Comment: Either uninstall then reinstall the printer driver or upgrade it to a newer version.  http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Photosmart-C6200-All-in-One-Printer-series/3194493/model/3194497

Answer (score -2):

After facing the error "Flow has stopped working", i've updated my sound driver "Conexant HD Audio Driver" and glad that it worked out.